# Do POSIX lfind()/lsearch() perform better than looping manually?

Tags: c, linux, algorithm, posix, libc

Do [`lfind`/`lsearch`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lsearch) perform better than a typical looping solution that checks each item until it matches? Is there any special sauce/reason that these functions exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably they are not more efficient that a homebrew version, maybe even a bit less since the comparison function can't be inlined.

But this is certainly not the point with them. They complete the API of the other search functions, in particular `bsearch` and `tsearch`.

Comment: I read the source code for lfind/lsearch in eglibc-2.11.1, there are no special optimizations made at all. The inability to inline is the biggest problem just as you've stated.

Answer (score 1):

Measure!

You can only know about performance by measuring. Things are definitely different on your computer and mine (I may even not have a POSIX compiant compiler cannot measure `lfind` myself). Thinks are different between different runs of a program.

So, if you need to know, try both the `lfind` and homebrew methods and **measure** several times.

Anyway ... `C` library functions may not have been written in `C`. If your `lfind` was written in `Python` I'd bet it would be slower than a homebrew method :)